# iCal: How do I add new event types with new colors?

Tags: ical

So iCal has "Work" and "Home" as two of its default event types associated with the colors green and blue respectively.

How do I add a third event type, say "School", and set its color to be something other than blue or green, say red?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add one on iCloud or on your Mac. Just navigate to '*File*' and create a '*New Calendar*'.

[image]

And there, you'll be able to create a new calendar, and with '*Get Info*' (right-click), you can choose your color.

[image]

[image]